# why are results of message queue on macOS and Ubuntu different

Tags: linux, message-queue, ubuntu-16.04, macos-sierra

Recently I'm learning process communication on Linux. And I wrote a C program to do the following things:

1. Process A sets up a message queue(like a mailbox)
2. Process B sends three messages "111", "222", "333" in order to the queue.
3. Process C reads messages in an order of "333", "111", "222" from the queue.
4. Process D deletes the queue.

I firstly wrote this program on Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked fine just as I thought:

[Results on Ubuntu 16.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBzeF.png)

However, when I compiled the same code and tried to run on macOS(Sierra 10.12.3), results are different from those on Ubuntu:

[Results on macOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSVi1.png)

No matter how I make changes to the code(e.g. sleep for a few seconds in Process A), the queue is always deleted before the third message sends.

Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_TEXT 1024

struct mymsg123
{
        long int priority;
        char text[MAX_TEXT];
};

int main()
{
    int msgid = -1; //message id
    struct mymsg123 data; //message to send

    //set up message queue(mailbox) in Process A
    msgid = msgget((key_t)1234, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if(msgid == -1)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "msgget failed in Process A with error: %d\n", errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Mailbox created in Process A\n");

    pid_t pid = fork(); //to create Process B
    if (pid < 0) {fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed in Process A"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    //child Process B
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        const char msg1[] = "111";
        //set the first message
        data.priority = 2;
        strcpy(data.text, msg1);
        //send the first message
        if (msgsnd(msgid, (void*)&data, MAX_TEXT, 0) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "msgsnd failed in Process B when sending msg1\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Sent msg %s, priority %ld to mailbox\n", data.text, data.priority);

        const char msg2[] = "222";
        //set the second message
        data.priority = 3;
        strcpy(data.text, msg2);
        //send the second message
        if (msgsnd(msgid, (void*)&data, MAX_TEXT, 0) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "msgsnd failed in Porcess B when sending msg2\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Sent msg %s, priority %ld to mailbox\n", data.text, data.priority);


        const char msg3[] = "333";
        //set the third message
        data.priority = 1;
        strcpy(data.text, msg3);
        //send the third message
        if (msgsnd(msgid, (void*)&data, MAX_TEXT, 0) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "msgsnd failed in Process B when sending msg3\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }   
        printf("Sent msg %s, priority %ld to mailbox\n", data.text, data.priority);
    }
    //parent Process A
    else
    {
        pid_t pid = fork(); //to create Process C
        if (pid < 0) {fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed in Process A"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
        //child process C
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            //receiving priority 1 message
            long int priority = 1;
            if(msgrcv(msgid, (void*)&data, BUFSIZ, priority, 0) == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "msgrcv failed with error in Process C when receiving priority 1 msg: %d\n", errno);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("Received priority 1 message in Process C from mailbox: %s\n", data.text);
            //receiving priority 2 message
            priority = 2;
            if(msgrcv(msgid, (void*)&data, BUFSIZ, priority, 0) == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "msgrcv failed with error in Prcess C when receiving priority 2 msg: %d\n", errno);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("Received priority 2 message in Process C from mailbox: %s\n", data.text);
            //receiving priority 3 message
            priority = 3;
            if(msgrcv(msgid, (void*)&data, BUFSIZ, priority, 0) == -1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "msgrcv failed with error in Process C when receiving priority 3 msg: %d\n", errno);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("Received priority 3 message in Process C from mailbox: %s\n", data.text);
        }
        //parent Process A
        else
        {
            pid_t pid = fork(); //to create Process D
            if (pid < 0) {fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed in Process A"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
            //child process D
            else if (pid == 0)
            {
                //sleep(10);
                if (msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "msgctl(IPC_RMID) failed in Process D\n");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                printf("Mailbox deleted in Process D\n");
            }
            //parent Process A
            else
                ;
        }
    }
    //sleep(10);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Advanced thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you printed the error message itself, rather than just the error codes.

Anyway, I think this is happening because [the message queue size appears to be 2048 bytes on macOS](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/message-queue-limit-for-mac-os-x.1025907/), but is usually something like 16384 on Linux. Coupled with your `MAX_TEXT` size of 1024, the third message cannot be sent as the queue is full. It may block until the first `msgrcv` call dequeues the first message, freeing up space, but macOS doesn't give man pages for this, so I'm going off the Linux pages.

Regardless, you have a race condition, because process D will delete the message queue immediately, without waiting for it to become empty. Thus, if process B blocks because the queue is full, and process D deletes it, B will return with an error. But this is all dependent on the scheduling of the processes, thus the race condition.

You can change the queue size in macOS, but you need to have superuser privileges for it to take effect. You could verify this without running as root by decreasing your `MAX_TEXT` define to something like 128 and verifying that it works on both.

Comment: Isn't there a race? The message queue can get deleted before being used.  Because there's no synchronization, there's no guarantee this can't happen. Process B being blocked on macOS makes this more likely.  On Linux I don't think it's guaranteed to work, either.

Comment: @CongMa Yep, I was editing my post to reflect that when you commented!

Comment: @tau Great! You should definitely clean up the race condition, regardless. There's not really a great way to do this with SYSV IPC, but the manpage for `msgctl` describes how you can get information on the queue. Process D could wait until a number of bytes or messages have been sent, for example. A global semaphore could also work.

Comment: Is it a good way to check whether message queue is empty or not before deleting following [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543338/check-unix-message-queue-if-empty-or-not)?

Comment: @tau Yes, but that's not going to solve your problem. A race condition occurs when the specific order in which processes or threads are scheduled changes the behavior of the program. Imagine your process D waited until the queue was "empty" before deleting it, but then process C drained the queue of messages 1 and 2 before process B could send message 3. Then the queue could be deleted, B would be waiting to send, and C would be waiting to receive. So it doesn't solve your issue. Proc C needs to signal D when all messages have been received, before D can actually delete the queue.